# asp.net localization: reporting on missing translations

Tags: asp.net, localization

Is is possible to hook into the localization engine somehow to produce a log of missing translations?

We have a localized web app, but not all the keys have translations.  In the case of a missing translation, the default (english, in this case) will show up for the user.  It would be nice to be able to log these "failures".

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you need to create your Custom Resource Provider.
Some examples on MSDN: [Extending the ASP.NET 2.0 Resource-Provider Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx#exaspnet20rpm_topic3)

Comment: I was hoping to be able to hook into the existing resource provider somehow.  Performance isn't an issue, since we're doing testing in a QA environment.